# understanding the logic in this recursive call

Tags: recursion

I'm new to the board and I apologize for coming off as a total noob, I'm just trying to wrap my head around the logic of this recursive method. I also searched the board for this question already and found something similar but didn't answer my question..

```
public int bunnyEars(int bunnies) {

  if(bunnies == 0) return 0;

  return 2 + bunnyEars(bunnies - 1);
}
```

I know that this compiles and works. But I'm unclear with the recursive call where 1 is subtracted from the number of bunnies being past in.. More precisely,  how can the number 1 be passed in as an argument bunnyEars(1) and still get the correct answer of 2 without being subtracted and equated to 0, thus exiting out of the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if arg is 1 in your function you get

return 2 + bunnyEars(1 - 1); which cals bummyEars(0) and return 0
so you get return 2+0; and your output is 2.

simple recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Try expanding the call chain. For example, if you invoke `bunnyEars(1)`, the `return` statement evaluates to:

```
2 + bunnyEars(1 - 1)
= 2 + bunnyEars(0)
= 2 + 0
= 2
```

Similarly, for `bunnyEars(2)`:

```
2 + bunnyEars(2 - 1)
= 2 + bunnyEars(1)
= 2 + 2 + bunnyEars(1 - 1)
= 2 + 2 + bunnyEars(0)
= 2 + 2 + 0
= 4
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the recursion works when the number 1 is passed in to it is because you are returning

```
2 + bunnyEars(bunnies - 1)
```

even if the number of bunnies is 0. By wrapping the second return in an else condition you will get the expected result of 0 being returned when you pass in bunnyEars(1).

Like so:

```
public int bunnyEars(int bunnies) {
    if(bunnies == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 2 + bunnyEars(bunnies - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: makes total sense when I look at it with the else statement.